# Copy LAMP in another computer

Tags: 12.04, server, lamp

I've LAMP installed in my laptop. Now my question is

1 ) `is this possible to copy LAMP directories to another computer.`

2) `if possible,which directories I need to copy??`

Thanks.

Comment: You mean copying the server files like /var/www/html ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have 2 computers with the same linux distributions, you would need to have LAMP installed on both computers.

Then, yes you can copy all files (configuration and relevant files) to the 2nd computer.

These could be depending on how you installed lamp,  the configuration files for apache, `/etc/http/*` or `/etc/apache/*` and the sites `/var/www/*`

Comment: Yes, Both computers are running on Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you know the answer of my 2nd question??

Comment: Just edited my answer, Marc-André Appel also gave a good answer

Answer (score 1):

If you have an identically setup of the machines (same Ubuntu version preferably, LAMP installed via `tasksel`), then you only need to copy `/etc/apache5/sites-*` (depending you have set-up multiple domain-names through "VirtualHost") and your www-data directory (by default `/var/www/`) to the other machine.

Concerning MySQL databases, you will have to do a `mysqldump` of the respective databases on the first machine, and import them on the other machine - via command-line or phpMyAdmin.